# Creating Google Sign In Authentication in Service Stack

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-razor

I know Service Stack offers a plugin to incorporate google sign in but we are on old version of service stack so we are creating the flow ourselves. We have a custom CredentialsAuthProvider where we are overriding TryAuthenticate and other methods according to our needs.

I could get the Id token from google apis but now I want to pass that to our custom credentailsAuthProvider which does multiple things including creating session and inserting rows into the database.

But I am facing a issue that it keeps failing the validation because I am passing an empty string for password and also I would like to tell my TryAuthenticate method that this request is coming from OAuth like a boolean?

Is there a way to hit TryAuthenticate without a password? Also, is this the right approach for Google Authentication in Service Stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TryAuthenticate` only exists when trying to create a custom `CredentialsAuthProvider`, for creating a custom OAuth Provider you should be inheriting `GoogleAuthProvider` or its `OAuth2Provider` base class instead.

Comment: I understand but what I was trying to do was, get the required details that we need from id token and follow the steps that we already have of creating the user and logging in using CredentailsAuthProvider. Is that possible without  passing in the password? Can I override the validation rules of password and also pass an extra parameter of checking if details are coming from OAuth or our simple web form?

Comment: @LearnAspNet Note CredentialsAuthProvider does have a feature which will allow you to [Authenticate as the user without a password](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#in-process-authenticated-requests) to be able to impersonate them, not sure if it's useful here though. If you want to attach an OAuth Sign In to the current user they should Authenticate with Google after they've Authenticated which will attach an additional Sign In Option to that user. If you just want to update User Info can just call AuthRepository.UpdateUserAuth() directly.

Comment: I do not think SkipPassword boolean will work for us. We are not trying to attach  OAuth to the current user but trying to create new users with Google Sign In. We are on older version of service stack so we do not have GoogleAuthProvider or OAuth2Provider to inherit our custom class.
Like I said, We have a custom Login page with new button Sign in with Google,Sign in with google follows the OAuth flow to get Id token and now we want to use that Id token to Register/login user without password.
How can I call AuthenticatePrivateRequest function directly from a Api call?

Comment: Basically I want a custom TryAuthenticate function to run for GoogleOAuth where I can change the session value of IsAuthenticated to be true and then call our own Custom OnAuthenticated option?

Comment: @LearnAspNet `CredentialsAuthProvider` is only for UserName/Password credentials not Google OAuth which doesn't have a TryAuthenticate function because it doesn't authenticate with Username/Password credentials. The `GoogleAuthProvider` is what lets you authenticate without a password, if you don't have access to it you would need to provide your own implementation, but you'd need to implement a custom OAuth2 provider not a `CredentialsAuthProvider`.

Comment: Thank you, Can you please tell me what is the way to call AuthenticatePrivateRequest function from Api? I am currently overriding it. Do I create a new Post Authenticate serivce?

Comment: @LearnAspNet If `SkipPasswordVerificationForInProcessRequests=true` and you're calling it from an InProcess Request it will call `AuthenticatePrivateRequest` instead otherwise you can override `Authenticate` in your custom provider and call AuthenticatePrivateRequest yourself.